# Why are different objects created when using globals in a file vs importing them?

Tags: python

Below is a simple code example that may help to explain my question.

**file_1.py**

```
from functools import lru_cache

from file_2 import add_stuff, add_stats


@lru_cache()
def add(x, y):
    return x + y


if __name__ == "__main__":
    add(1, 2)
    add(1, 2)
    add(3, 4)
    print(add.cache_info)
    print(add.cache_info())
    add_stuff(1, 2)
    add_stuff(3, 4)
    add_stats()
```

**file_2.py**

```
def add_stuff(x, y):
    from file_1 import add

    add(x, y)


def add_stats():
    from file_1 import add

    print(add.cache_info)
    print(add.cache_info())
```

And the output looks like this:

```
<built-in method cache_info of functools._lru_cache_wrapper object at 0x017E9E48>
CacheInfo(hits=1, misses=2, maxsize=128, currsize=2)
<built-in method cache_info of functools._lru_cache_wrapper object at 0x017E9D40>
CacheInfo(hits=0, misses=2, maxsize=128, currsize=2)
```

When I use the function inside of the file it was defined in, the function object is different from when another file imports it. Which means that for things like lru_cache, if you didn't realize this, you could be populating two caches inside of your process/threads if you don't keep the cached functions inside of a different file from where they are used.

My question is, is this a python gotcha to look out for? Or is there documentation somewhere that I just never read that explains this more in depth? I looked at the lru_cache documentation, and this was not called out there as anything to be aware of.

Comment: You're defining the `add()` function twice. Once in the main code when you run `file_1.py`, and again when you import `file_1`. Each instance has its own cache. You should generally avoid circular imports like this.

Comment: Relevant: [`__main__` — Top-level code environment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html)

Comment: You could simplify this MRE by replacing `add` with a simple global variable `a = 1`, putting `a = 2` under the main guard, and `from file_1 import a; print(a)` in a function in `file_2`. For yucks, you could also add `from __main__ import a; print(a)` in another function.

Comment: Regarding `print(add.cache_info)`, you're getting a new `method` instance each time you execute this, even if there *is* just one instance `add`.

Answer (score 2):

> When I use the function inside of the file it was defined in, the function object is different from when another file imports it.

Yes; there are two separate caches, because each is decorating a separate function object. The reason there are two separate function objects is because there are two separate **modules** created from the same source code.

One of these modules was created by `from file_1 import add`, which causes a module to be cached in the `sys.modules` with the key `'file_1'` and a `__name__` attribute of `file_1`. (Subsequent uses of `import` will look up this module in the cache).

The other one is created by running `file_1.py` as the main script. This causes a module with a `__name__` attribute of `__main__` to be created.

**This is why and how** the `if __name__ == '__main__':` trick works. The global variables available to a module - i.e., what you get by using `globals()` - come from **attributes of the module object**. Top-level scripts **are also represented with module objects** - they just aren't imported using `import` (although they **are** created using much of the same machinery, and cached; a `'__main__'` key will appear in `sys.modules`). That's where the information comes from, and thus why `__name__` exists as a global variable in normal circumstances.

> is this a python gotcha to look out for? Or is there documentation somewhere that I just never read that explains this more in depth? I looked at the lru_cache documentation, and this was not called out there as anything to be aware of.

It isn't explained in the `lru_cache` documentation because it isn't `lru_cache`'s fault. It would happen with any decorator. In fact, it would happen with any code that makes the separate identity of the function objects relevant. For example, if we create this `module_example.py`:

```
def example():
    print(example.module)
example.module = __name__

if __name__ == '__main__':
    example()
```

(The reoccurrence of `__name__` should make it obvious what is going on - although, of course, we could even just use `__name__` directly in the function)

Now we test the code in interactive mode - run it, use the global function, and then import the module and use the imported function:

```
$ python -i module_example.py 
__main__
>>> example()
__main__
>>> import module_example
>>> module_example.example()
module_example
>>> quit()
$
```

This is only a gotcha insofar as **expecting a module to work as both the top-level code and as something importable, imposes some design considerations**. Normally, if the code is intended to be imported, the "driver" code block (if any) will just do an informal test; or offer a simple, one-off UI for the module's functionality that *doesn't care* about consistency with an imported-module version of the same code.

Alternately put: the real problem here is a **circular import**. `file_1` is indirectly importing itself to get at its own functionality, and it only "works" because of the implicit renaming of the module to `__main__` the first time.